# What is the best way to automatically update the references inside the projects, after changing the structures of the used libraries?

Tags: javascript, package.json, javascript-import

After merging two javascript (react) libraries into a new one, I need to update the references inside the consumer projects, with the new paths.

The best way I can think of to automate this would be through a shell script - get the components exported together with their path, then parse through each file and update the import statement.

Is there a better way of doing this? does this sound like a decent solution, or am I completely outdated?

Comment: You could be lazy like me, and do some regex find/replace in your favorite IDE if you don't have too many different nested relative imports

Comment: good remark, but we are changing the structure in the modules also. I know some IDEs have this capability of autoimporting missing references and I was wondering If I can leverage that in any way.